# How to make functional rules not depend on an argument?

Tags: functions, function-construction, replacement, rule, arguments

Consider the following:

```
rule = f[x] -> Sin[x]
```

if I now do, say:

```
f[y] /. rule
```

this does not work, because the rule wants the argument to specifically be x. Of course, I could do:

```
f[x] /. rule /. x -> y
```

but I really would be able to "clean" the rule of the input.
As an example, If we use NDSolve to solve an ODE, we obtain a rule of the form:

```
{f -> InterpolatingFunction["stuff"]}
```

this is nice insofar that I can apply this rule to f, where the argument can be anything I wish.
So, the question is, If I ALREADY have a rule as above, is there a nice way to "remove" the "[x]" part of all the functions, in the sense described above?

Comment: Why not use `rule = f -> Sin`?

Comment: The reason is that the rule I have is obtained by solving an algebraic equation for a variable f(x). The output of Solve gives you a rule, which then has the explicit argument input, unfortunately. That is why I specified how to change the rule in the desired way. Except if we can force Solve to behave like NDSolve, insofar that it "forgets" about the argument (both for the LHS and RHS of the rule)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While John Doty's answer works pretty well, if you want to obtain a pure function as *rhs* of your rule like in your `InterpolatingFunction` example, you can do something like

```
rule = f[x] -> Sin[x];
newrule = f -> Block[
 {x},
 Function @@ List[{x}, f[x] /. rule]
]
(*f -> Function[{x}, Sin[x]]*)
```

Comment: Quite interesting. I am new to Mathematica and I have never encountered the use of @@ before. What is the use of it?

Comment: `f @@ expr` (spaces are optional) is a shortcut for `Apply[f, expr]`, which changes the head of `expr` to `f`. Consult `Apply` in the Documentation Center for details.

Answer (score 5):

It's just like defining a function. Make `x` the name of a pattern, not a literal symbol:

```
rule = f[x_] -> Sin[x]
f[y] /. rule
(* Sin[y] *)
```

Comment: If you do this, you should generally use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`).

Comment: I see! It really was a simple answer. Thank you very much!